# Distinguishing ID's

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server-2008

This is my query:

```
$tsql = "SELECT *
FROM 
    dbo.messages m INNER JOIN
    dbo.contacts c
    ON m.contactID = c.ID
WHERE 
    assigned='{$_COOKIE['member_name']}'
ORDER BY
    m.status DESC, m.ID DESC";
```

This returns the contact ID but not the message ID.  How do I get it to show:

```
<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>
```

But with the message ID and not the contact ID in an HTML form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access id of c table using cid, and id of m table as mid

like $row['cid'] and  $row['mid']

```
    $tsql = "SELECT m.*, c.*, c.id as cid, m.id as mid
    FROM 
        dbo.messages m INNER JOIN
        dbo.contacts c
        ON m.contactID = c.ID
    WHERE 
        assigned='{$_COOKIE['member_name']}'
    ORDER BY
        m.status DESC, m.ID DESC";
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I was trying m.ID and it wasn't working at all.